# Axis label values are generated dynamic, however require specific labels to be displayed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart, axis-labels

I am trying to dynamically generate axis label values as follows.

```
Dim dt As DataTable
dt = ds.Tables(0)

Dim y2max As Double = dt.Compute("max(return)", String.Empty) + 0.001
Dim y2min As Double = dt.Compute("min(return)", String.Empty) - 0.001
Dim ymax As Double = dt.Compute("max(TC_" & TC & ")", String.Empty) + 0.005
Dim ymin As Double = dt.Compute("min(TC_" & TC & ")", String.Empty) - 0.005
```

And generate the following chart.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkyH7.png

I am able to achieve desired scaling with this approach , however i want by PRIMARY Y label values to have "1". Can i set an appropriate interval or format Y label values to achieve this. 
**This is what i wish to achieve**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0yQF.png

I am not concerned about the interval values/length, however i need my Blue line series to start with 1.

Answer (score 0):

WRONG ANSWER: *I think you are looking for the `AxisY.IntervalOffset` property.* Why is it wrong? Because it shifts the labels. It just happened that it *looked* right in my previous attempt.

RIGHT ANSWER: If you set the `AxisY.Crossing` property to 1 then it will force it to use 1 as a label value, and calculate the other labels appropriately. You then need to set `AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = False` to avoid zero being included on the axis and `AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = False` to make the x-axis labels appear at the bottom edge of the chart.

So...

```
Sub GenerateChart()
    Chart1.Legends.Clear()
    Chart1.Series.Clear()

    ' generate some sample data
    Dim s1 As New Series
    For i = 0 To 180 Step 2
        s1.Points.AddXY(i, Math.Sin(Math.PI * i / 60) * 0.004 + 1)
    Next

    Chart1.Series.Add(s1)
    Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    Chart1.Series(0).BorderWidth = 2

    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = False
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Crossing = 1
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = False

    ' avoid the label "1.000" being formatted as "1"
    Dim labelFormat = "0.000"
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle = New LabelStyle With {.Format = labelFormat}

End Sub
```

Gives

[image: chart]

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation @andrew. IntervalOffset suits well for the purpose, however in my case the Y label axis are generated dynamically and hence the offset value cannot be fixed. It needs to be dynamic too.

Comment: @user3715501 You can calculate the IntervalOffset yourself - it doesn't have to be a fixed amount.

Comment: @user3715501 I must apologise for my previous attempt: after more investigation it turned out to be wrong, or at best mostly wrong. I think my new attempt is the correct answer - I gave it more extensive testing.

Comment: Great. ALmost there! just the label missing. My output with                               Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = False
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Crossing = 1
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = False     is http://imgur.com/7VhX4qz

Comment: Well that's awkward. Have you tried something like `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 0.02`?

Comment: Yes, didnt work. I am trying out different options. No results as of now, I would update the post once i get it. Thanks